# Best way to pass CGFloat by reference to another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In `ClassA`, I have a `CGFloat` value `x` that I want to pass by reference to `ClassB` such that if I make a change to the `CGFloat` in `ClassA`, it will be reflected in the reference to `x` in `ClassB`. Also, when I pass it to `ClassB`, I want to store it as a property.

I've thought about using a CGFloat pointer, but I'm struggling to figure out the proper syntax to make it a property:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat *x;
```

And then to dereference it:

```
self->x
```

I thought about using `NSNumber` but there is no way to set the value using `NSNumber` such that it will update in `ClassB`. I thought about giving up and making a wrapper class to store the `CGFloat`, but this seems like overkill.

What is the best pattern to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought about giving up and making a wrapper class to store the CGFloat, but this seems like overkill.

The advantage of this approach is safety, you create an object, both classes reference it, and ARC takes care of the memory management.

The class is easy to define, for example:

```
@interface ABShare1 : NSObject
@property CGFloat x;
@end

@implementation ABShare1
@end
```

(in a `.h` & `.m` file – same for other examples)

A class using this would be something like:

```
@implementation ClassA
{
   ABShare1 *one;
}
...
one = ABShare1.new; // somewhere in initialisation
...
... one.x = 42; ... z = one.x * 24; ...
```

*Note: the above stores the `ABShare1` reference in a private instance variable, you can store it in a property if you wish but there is no need to.*

You can call a method on another class passing the object, e.g.:

```
ClassB *myB;
...
[myB using:(ABShare1 *)sharedVariable];
```

and that other class can keep the reference as long as it requires, memory management is automatic.

> I've thought about using a CGFloat pointer

This is the standard C (a subset of Objective-C) way of "passing by reference".

You can store a `CGFloat *` in a property, all "object" valued properties in Objective-C just store pointers (e.g. `@property NSString *name;` stores a pointer to an `NSString` object).

You must create the variable that the `CGFloat *` references, the equivalent of `new` or `alloc`/`init` in Objective-C. You can use the address of a variable, e.g. something like:

```
CGFloat actualX;
CGFloat *x = &actualX;
```

but you have to manually ensure that the referenced variable, `actualX`, lives at least as long as its pointer, stored in `x`, is in use – failure to do that results in a *dangling pointer*.

The other option is to dynamically allocate the storage, the direct equivalent of `new`, e.g. something like:

```
CGFloat *x = malloc(sizeof(CGFloat));
```

However you are now responsible for determining when the storage is no longer required and releasing it (using `free()`).

The first solution to you is "overkill" – maybe because while you are freed from concerns over memory management you don't get a "variable" but two functions/methods to get/set a value.

The second solution is closest to feeling like a "variable", you just use `*sharedVariable` rather than `sharedVariable`. However while the manual memory management required is standard for C programmers, it is not for Objective-C programmers.

A third approach mixes the two building on how structures (`struct`) in C can be used: to share a collection of variables rather than share each one individually by address, instead define a `struct` with a member for each variable, allocate one and share its address, something like:

```
typedef struct ABShare
{  CGFloat x;
   CGFloat y;
} ABShare;

ABShare *one = malloc(sizeof(ABShare));
one->x = 42;
one->y = 24;
```

The above has the same memory management issues as the second solution, but we can convert it to a very close Objective-C equivalent:

```
@interface ABShare : NSObject
{
@public // required
   CGFloat x;
   CGFloat y;
}
@end

@implementation ABShare
@end
```

*Note: Objective-C classes are effectively implemented using `struct`s, indeed the first Objective-C compilers actually translated them into C `struct` code.*

Using this is very close to the C:

```
ABShare *one = ABShare.new;
one->x = 42;
one->y = 24;
```

Same "variable" look as C but with automatic memory management.

This last scheme is essentially how Objective-C manages sharing variables when a block is created – all the local variables accessed by the block are moved into a dynamically allocated object/struct and the variables then accessed using `->`.

Which is best in Objective-C? The first and the third are both "Objective-C" style, the second is usually avoided accept when interacting with C APIs. Of the first and third pick whichever feels "right" semantically, rather than concerns over performance, to you. HTH

Answer (score 1):

`[NSMutableData dataWithLength:sizeof(CGFloat)]` and cast `mutableBytes` to `CGFloat*`

You can implement getter and setter of property `@property(nonatomic) CGFloat x` -without pointer